# asp.net session object being set to empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a Session object in my asp.net app that I am setting to the userID value. The session object gets instantiated in the gloal.asax. The value is being set on a button_click event when a user signs in and has been authenticated.

However, somewhere somehow in my app, the Session is being set to Empty. How can I determine where and how the session object is being set to empty?

Comment: Can you post the code that is in the global.asax?  Usually, session would not need to be instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a global search for the session variable within your project. Put a break point on all of the lines. and then closely step through the application. I just had the same bug two days ago. Took four hours stepping through 80+ pages. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of reasons this may happen:

- Are you modifying the variable on `Page_Load()`?
- Is your browser returning the session cookie? (You can verify using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/))

In my experience this kind of problem will almost certainly be addressed by the above.

Comment: Not on the page_load. I do have it in the global.asax session_start and then on button_click events is where the session value is being written or read from.

Comment: Also make sure the session ID isn't changing from when you create the variable in session_start to when you are trying to retrieve it in the click event.

Comment: Ok I would double check what you've got in your global.asax, and that it isn't running for each request.

Comment: @m.edmondson I verified that the global.asax line is only being called when I  launch the application.

Comment: @JeffSiver I am certain the session ID is not changing

Comment: Have you tried enabling tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx) and seeing if anything is jumping out about the session information?